# Merge cells with similar but different data, different spelling

Tags: cell, tableau-api

I am trying Tableau with data extracted from Salesforce. The input includes a "Country" record were the row have different spellings for the same thing.

Example: Cananda, CANADA, CAnada etc.

Is there a way to fix this in Tableau?

Comment: Not automatically.  You could create a calculated field with if elses though for all the known misspellings.  Likely you'll want to clean your data before importing to Tableau.  Checkout Excel's fuzzy logic add-on

Comment: Along with the other suggestions and answers, I would add (on the assumption you are hitting a production instance of Salesforce and not a data warehouse) to consider changing the data in Salesforce itself. Find the offending records and clean them. I've had times where the time and code to code case statements against all the variations outweighed the cost and effort to clean the data at its source.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is create a group field based on your Country field.

Select Country in the data pane on the left side bar, right click and choose Create Group. Select elements that you want to group together put them into a single group, say Canada, that contains all variations of spelling.

This new group field initially has a name of Country (group). You may want to rename it Country_Corrected. (Or even better, rename the first field, Country_Original, and call the group field simply Country. Then you can hide Country_Original)

Groups are implemented using SQL case statements. They have many uses, but one application is to easily tolerate some inconsistent spellings in your data source without having to change your data. In general, you can specify several transformations like this that take effect at query and visualization time. For very large data sets, or for very complicated transformations, you may eventually want to push some of them upstream in your data pipeline to get better performance. But make those optimizations later when you've proven the necessity.

Answer (score 0):

If the differences are just in case (upper vs lower), you can right-click the Country dimension, and create a calculated field called something like "New Country", and use the following formula to make the case consistent:

upper([Country])

Use this new "New Country" calc dimension instead of your "Country" dimension, and it will group them all without case sensitivity, and display as uppercase. Or you can use "lower" instead of "upper" if preferred.